# How to iterate database values by date for google charts

Tags: php, mysql, loops, charts, linechart

I have seen similar questions but still do not understand how it woks.. I have this while loop looping my DB for dates, leads and sold. For each date in the DB I would like to show the daily leads and sold for each date in the DB in a line chart.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE source = 'website' ORDER BY date ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $sold = $row['sold'];
         $visit= $row['visit'];
         $date= $row['date'];
    }else{

    }       
}
```

Here is the chart script -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartl);

  function drawChartl() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', 'Leads', 'Sold'],
        ['1st',  6,       2],
        ['2nd',  3,       1],
        ['3rd',  2,       3],
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Internet Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'top' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>


<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see following snippet...

need an array that holds all the data --> `$json`

then add each row to `$json` --> `$dataRow`

then write the result to the `javascript` --> `data.addRows(<?= $jsonstring ?>);`

try something like this, probably need to format the date too...

```
<?php
  $json = array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE source = 'website' ORDER BY date ASC";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $dataRow = array(
              $row['date'],
              $row['visit'],
              $row['sold']
          );
          array_push($json, $dataRow);
      }
  }

  $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
?>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'callback': function () {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [{type: 'string', label: 'Date'}, {type: 'number', label: 'Leads'}, {type: 'number', label: 'Sold'}]
      ]);

      data.addRows(<?= $jsonstring ?>);

      var options = {
        title: 'Internet Performance',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'top' }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    },
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });
</script>

<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, here's the PHP Fiddle I used to test --> [test line chart](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r4cq-pkcg)

Comment: Works great! This answers that problem but what if I have multiple visits for one date, it shows the same date multiple times for each.. How can I iterate over each date for leads for that day but only show the dates once? so like 07/14 = 4 visits instead of showing 07/14 4 times on the chart..  Thanks again!

Comment: i would recommend adjusting the sql --> `SELECT date, sum(visit) as "visit", sum(sold) as "sold" FROM customers WHERE source = 'website' group by date ORDER BY date ASC`

Comment: Thank you, I thought about adjusting the sql but the values for sold and visit are strings 'yes' and 'no' so I iterate with a if statement to get the number of visits..

Comment: maybe this sql instead then --> `SELECT date, sum(case when visit = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as "visit", sum(case when sold = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as "sold" FROM customers WHERE source = 'website' group by date ORDER BY date ASC`

Comment: Ahh didnt know I could use sum(case when..) thank you but it is throwing this error - Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type number in column index 1 Thank you @WhiteHat

Comment: I created a new question for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425974/how-to-show-unique-dates-when-outputting-data-to-charts-in-php  Big thanks to @WhiteHat

Comment: when I echo out visit it gives me an array of numbers instead of yes or no..so it seems to work but I still get duplicate dates.. could it be because the DATETIME also has minutes and seconds so it doesn't see it as a duplicate?

Comment: yes, would need to format in sql, and group on same