# How to show unique dates when outputting data to charts in php

Tags: php, sql, json, charts, sum

Based on a answer I got earlier from @WhiteHat (Thank you) I cannot seem to get the dates to show unique so I made this a new question as its an extension question..

I have a DB that has 3 columns - date, visits, sold.. Visit values are strings yes or no as well as sold = yes or no..I would like to display how many leads and sold for each day of the month. The db has a new row for each lead and sold so there are multiple dates that are duplicated for each lead and sold.

It throws this error - Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type number in column index 1

```
<?php
$json = array();
$sql = "SELECT date, sum(case when visit = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as 'visit', sum(case when sold = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as sold FROM customers    WHERE source = 'website' group by date ORDER BY date ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sold = $row["sold"];
    $visit = $row["visit"];
    $date = $row["date"];
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $ndate = date("m/d", $time);
      $dataRow = array(
          $ndate,
          $row['visit'],
          $row['sold'],
      );
      array_push($json, $dataRow);
  }
  }
  $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
 ?>
```

Here is the chart script

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {
'callback': function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [{type: 'string', label: 'Date'}, {type: 'number', label: 'Leads'}, {type: 'number', label: 'Sold'}]
  ]);

  data.addRows(<?= $jsonstring ?>);

  var options = {
    title: 'Internet Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'top' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
},
'packages': ['corechart']
});
</script>

<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 1900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: Look at the HTML source that is generated (view source in your browser): what is in the line `data.addRows`? Is it as expected? Also try to add this option to json_encode: `json_encode($json, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: @trincot it has all the data but not showing unique dates and adding up the leads, I think my issue is formatting the date to not use hours min and sec..I am not sure though.

Comment: Try this: in your SQL query, replace `select date` with `select date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date`. You may need to do the same in the `group by`, but only if your date field has time indications.

Comment: ya still getting duplicate dates, and getting that error thrown.. here is my sql - SELECT date_format(date, '%y-%m-%d') as date, sum(case when visit = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as 'visit', sum(case when sold = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as sold FROM customers WHERE source = 'website' group by date ORDER BY date ASC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest do the grouping per day like this in your SQL statement:

```
$json = array();
$sql = "SELECT   date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as day,
                 sum(case when visit = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as visit, 
                 sum(case when sold = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as sold 
        FROM     customers
        WHERE    source = 'website'
        GROUP BY day
        ORDER BY day ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die('"error in sql"');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json[] = array(
        $row['day'],
        $row['visit'],
        $row['sold'],
    );
}
$jsonstring = json_encode($json,  JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
if (json_last_error()) $jsonstring = '"' . json_last_error_msg() . '"'; 
// somewhere you need to output the data:
echo $jsonstring;
```

The dates are generated in the yyyy-mm-dd format, which is the ISO standard. I am not sure if this is acceptable for the graph library you use, although it should, because you defined it as type string. If the date format is an issue, then change it in the SQL statement accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Ultimately I am getting duplicate days 07/14, 07/14  so wouldnt I need to group by the day? I want to now how many leads I got on that day instead of showing a duplicate date for every lead that day..  Thanks @trincot !

Comment: I don't see how you get `07/14`, as that is not the format I provided in the code. So if you want daily totals, then can I assume that the PHP code which you have in your question, and which *explicitly* turns dates into their months equivalent, is *not* what you wanted?

Comment: This will not return any data either

Comment: Im not specifically getting that format, you are right I was just giving an example

Comment: @RyanD, I suppose the full PHP has the `echo`, as it was already confirmed that the final HTML has the data.

Comment: Im not specifically getting that format, you are right I was just giving an example, yes what is important is the days of the month. I would like the date to be as follows - [07/14,5,2],[07/15,3,2],[07/16,2,1], as [date,leads,sold].. Not sure what you mean by has the echo?

Comment: So without the year part? How will that work in December and January?

Comment: The blank chart displays but now its not outputting any data in html,, I can have the year thats not a big deal but the program is usually just going to be for month to date stats so the year isnt that big of a deal but mostly daily totals

Comment: Please provide the data you see in your HTML source in the line `data.addRows(...);`, and put it in an additional paragraph in your question. That will be helpful to see what you are getting.

Comment: It doesn't display any data in html, just a blank chart with no errors, I was getting data before I changed the sql to your suggestion just wanted to clarify..But when it had data it was duplicates and threw that error

Comment: thank you! this gives me the correct data - [["2016-07-12","1","0"],["2016-07-13","0","0"],["2016-07-14","2","2"],["2016-07-15","3","2"],["2016-07-16","7","3"]] when I use the echo and in the html but the chart doesnt display and I get this error - VM2765:222 Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type number in column index 1

Comment: Could you add the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option to the `json_encode`? I added this in my answer, and I also added some error checking.

Comment: Also, could you put back your original code in your question? Otherwise my answer does not make sense. You can always add to your question, but please leave the original essential parts in tact.

Comment: It works! Thanks @trincot I must of had a hitch in the giddy up somewhere but after a refresh it works perfect thank you!